# Visual Studio macro that can locate a file in solution explorer ? File is located inside a Solution folder that is collapsed

Tags: visual-studio, directory, solution, locate

There are few macros and VS plugins out there to locate a file in solution explorer. That is very handy. However, most solutions don't support the case where the file is located in a Visual Studio Solution Folder that is collapsed.

Apparently the last version of Resharper has found a way around this but I'm after a free solution. Preferably a Macro so that I don't have run a full plugin.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd have said Resharper but you beat me. Well worth the money none the less.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

http://weblogs.asp.net/kdente/archive/2008/04/30/locating-the-active-item-in-solution-explorer.aspx